# Touch events in JavaScript perform two different actions

Tags: javascript, events, touch

Since I experienced a very strange issue with different touch event libraries (like hammer.js and quo.js) I decided to develop the events I need on my own. The Issue I'm talking about is that a touch is recognized twice if a hyperlink appears on the spot where I touched the screen. This happens on iOS as well as Android.

Imagine an element on a web page that visually changes the content of the screen if you touch it. And if the new page shows a hyperlink (`<a href="">`) at the same spot where I touched the screen before that new hyperlink gets triggered as well.

Now I developed my own implementation and I noticed: I'm having the same problem! Now is the question: Why?

What I do is the following (yes, I'm using jQuery):

**(see source code below #1)**

- This function is only used with some special elements, not hyperlinks. So hyperlinks still have the default behavior.
- The problem only affects hyperlinks. It doesn't occur on other elements that use the event methods showed above.

So I can imagine that not a click event is fired on the same element I touch but a click 'action' is performed at the same spot where I touched the screen after the touch event was processed. At least this is what it feels like. And since I only catch the click event on the element I actually touch I don't catch the click event on the hyperlink - and actually that shouldn't be necessary.

Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

---

## Full source codes

### #1 - attatch event to elements

`$elements` is a jQuery object returned by $( selector );
`callback` is the function that should be called if a tap is detected

```
helper.registerTapEvent = function($elements, callback) {
    var touchInfo = {
        maxTouches: 0
    };

    function evaluate(oe) {
        var isSingleTouch = touchInfo.maxTouches === 1,

        positionDifferenceX = Math.abs(touchInfo.startX - touchInfo.endX),
        positionDifferenceY = Math.abs(touchInfo.startY - touchInfo.endY),
        isAlmostSamePosition = positionDifferenceX < 15 && positionDifferenceY < 15,

        timeDifference = touchInfo.endTime - touchInfo.startTime,
        isShortTap = timeDifference < 350;

        if (isSingleTouch && isAlmostSamePosition && isShortTap) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(oe);
        }
    }

    $elements
    .on('touchstart', function(e) {
        var oe = e.originalEvent;

        touchInfo.startTime = oe.timeStamp;
        touchInfo.startX = oe.changedTouches.item(0).clientX;
        touchInfo.startY = oe.changedTouches.item(0).clientY;
        touchInfo.maxTouches = oe.changedTouches.length > touchInfo.maxTouches ? oe.touches.length : touchInfo.maxTouches;
    })
    .on('touchend', function(e) {
        var oe = e.originalEvent;

        oe.preventDefault();

        touchInfo.endTime = oe.timeStamp;
        touchInfo.endX = oe.changedTouches.item(0).clientX;
        touchInfo.endY = oe.changedTouches.item(0).clientY;

        if (oe.touches.length === 0) {
            evaluate(oe);
        }
    })
    .on('click', function(e) {
        var oe = e.originalEvent;

        oe.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

### #2 - the part how the page transition is done

`$subPageElem` is a jQuery object of the page that should be displayed
`$subPageElem.prev()` returns the element of the current page that hides (temporarily) when a new page shows up.

```
$subPageElem.css({
    webkitTransform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
    transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
}).prev().css({
    webkitTransform: 'translate3d(-5%,0,-100px)',
    transform: 'translate3d(-5%,0,-100px)'
});
```

I should also mention that the new page `$subPageElem` is generated dynamically and inserted into the DOM. I. e. that link that gets triggered (but shouldn't) doesn't even exist in the DOM when I touch/release the screen.

Comment: For mouse, if you mousedown on one element, and mouseup on another, there will be no `click` event. I'm guessing you're seeing a violation of this with touch events? I don't have a touch device at hand so I can't confirm your finding.

Comment: touchend is used in ipad and click for all other devices so u need to check a condition whether if(isIpad){...} and u should add the touchend code into it by doing this behaviour ur talking will not occur..I mean to say u should have come code that checks the browser the app opens into..

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I don't know how this could help me. The new page only appears **after** I release the finger. So the finger never touches the link that will be triggered (but shouldn't).

Comment: @codebreaker I don't want to use the click event because of its delay. And the touch events do work properly. They just do "too much". And there's no difference in behavior between iOS and Android. So I don't know why I should differ the OS.

Comment: See if ur app is going to work on both iOS and And'd devices then all the events u declare for activity should be touchend for iOS and click for all other..u can easily achieve this using check browser code if u want i can update the code.. only this way u can stop the behaviour.. i am jq coder myself declaring just touchend and click will cause results as u have mentioned...

Comment: @codebreaker okay, it works on iOS now so the OS does make a difference now. I expected the same behavior as with the other libraries and I couldn't test it before because the MacBook was updating to OS X 10.9 -- but does that mean I really **have to** use `click` on non-iOS devices? There's no way to avoid it? Can you tell me what exactly is happening so I can understand what's going wrong here so maybe I can find a better solution in my special case? Thank you! (btw: detecting the OS is no problem since I'm also using PhoneGap here)

Comment: K actually touchend in ios equals to click on other devices(Dsktps,android devices) so if u don't want to use click u can use the tap plugin which performs event equal to click for touch enabled browsers.. here is the link..http://plugins.jquery.com/tap/...and as far i said u before u need to wrap events for ios and other devices separately for the activity in the app..

Comment: Are you sure about that 'touchend ... equals ... click'? Android (actually all mobile browsers) also fully support(s) touch events such as `touchstart` and `touchend`, since they are a HTML standard. (see caniuse.com) But it also triggers `click` at the same time because otherwise a lot of web sites wouldn't work on mobile devices without changing them. So I can't really follow you here.. -- I checked the source of the Tap Plugin. It pretty much does the same as I'm doing, just a little bit more advanced. But I will test it, nonetheless.

Comment: @codebreaker Unfortunately the jQuery Tap plugin has the same issue. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: can u post the code u have added and tested for me to help...

Comment: @codebreaker edited the original question above. Hope that's what you are asking for.

Comment: @AndreasLinnert Hey, I'm probably a bit late to the party, but I noticed a strange behavior as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245555/misplaced-clickable-area-due-to-class-toggle-height-change-on-touch-event Is this the same behavior as you noticed here?